# TypeError:__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am facing **TypeError:__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)** error when calling below function:

**Code Snippet:**

`super(abc, self).__init__(incoming, **kwargs);`

Comment: Could you post the full error message and the trace please?

Comment: Where does the actual error occur, and how do you call the code that triggers it?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “abc.py", line 35, in <module>
    new_layer = abc(x, perc=98.4, alpha=0.1, beta=tf.constant(0.5), tight=100.0, name="new_layer")
  File “abc.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(abc, self).__init__(incoming, **kwargs);
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: It looks like `Layer.__init__` does not accept any arguments (i.e., only `self`). You're passing in `(self, incoming, name='new_layer')`.

Comment: Could you kindly explain in details?

Answer (score 1):

**Before**

```
super(abc, self).__init__(incoming, **kwargs);
```

After modification where "incoming" need to be removed.

```
super(abc, self).__init__(**kwargs);
```